# Unable to run Windows Container on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, windows-container

I am trying to run a Windows container on Google cloud and get this error...

C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage \?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\0a04539f9f077acf8dbc35f493c70f4ba3f75a65aff70fd20281886b835c69ef\UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified.

There is utterly nothing wrong with the container.  I have run the same container on my Windows dev box, on Azure and finally on AWS without any issues.

The Dockerfile looks like this...

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime

WORKDIR /.

COPY License/ /License/
COPY Input/ /Input/
COPY Engine/ /Engine/
COPY redist/ /Engine/
COPY Scripts/ /
RUN mkdir Output

CMD ["powershell.exe","./runxx.ps1"]
```

I have created 3 VM instances on Google Cloud platform, first with 1803 Windows Server with containers, then 1709 Window Server with containers and finally Windows Server Datacenter 2016 Core.

1803 was a complete failure.  The docker installed was running Linux containers.  So when pulling the windows container you get the strange error "Unknown blob...".  Took a while to figure this out.  No way it seems to switch to windows containers via the command line.

UPDATE:  I tried the 1803 image again and the Windows container runs fine now.  Not sure what when wrong with the first 1803 VM I created.  I am still wondering why I couldn't get Windows Server 2016 working.

I got further with 1709.  Docker was running windows containers, but when I tried to run the container I got the error indicating that my docker image required Windows Server 2016.

So finally I built a VM with Windows Server 2016 Core.  There is no container optimized version to I had to install Docker myself.  I followed carefully the script https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/#docker_on_windows which includes quite a few ridiculous workarounds for known issues. Briefly you need to install docker with

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
```

Then the work arounds for known issues...

```
netsh netkvm setparam 0 *RscIPv4 0
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters /v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0 /f
```

And after all this it still does not work and gives me the error reported at the top.

What am I doing wrong?  I have to conclude that Google Cloud is simply not ready to run Windows containers.

EDIT:  On further investigation I have determined that I can run a windows container built from Windows nanoserver but not one built from the full .NET Framework.

i.e. if my Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
```

the container will run.  If it contains

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5-runtime
```

or

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime
```

it will fail. Why is that?  And where does this "failed to register layer" error come from?

Comment: You installed 1803 windows server and it was pulling Linux images by default for dotnet-framework? There are none existent. Go back to 1803 and try to just pull windowsservercore latest what do you get?

Comment: No,  @GregorySuvalian, the docker daemon on the 1803 image is set up for Linux containers...the unknown blob error seems to be emblematic of this problem.  This is the default setting for Docker when you install it on the desktop.  You need to manually switch docker to run windows containers.  So I simply believe this is an error in the way the 1803 images was setup.

Comment: This is not correct, on server edition it's different and defaults to process isolation and windows containers only

Comment: Paste output of docker info on 1803

Comment: Also try to use `FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime-windowsservercore-1803`

Comment: Well @GregorySuvalian indeed you are right!  I tried 1803 again and my Windows container runs fine unmodifiied.  Not sure what went wrong the first time.  I deleted that 1st 1803 VM so there is no way to find out.  There is still the question of why I cannot get the Windows Server 2016 image running properly.

Comment: What is exact issue are you facing with Windows 2016 image? If you image is based off 1803 you will not be able to run it on Windows 2016 LTSC

Comment: @GregorySuvalian the ones described above.  I can run an image built from nanoserver but not one built from dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime or 3.5-runtime.  Both of these images are based on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: You can not `run` or `build` images? Whenever you build images make sure you specify exact version of image along with underlying OS to avoid issues with compatibility between base OS images. For example `4.7.2-runtime-windowsservercore-ltsc2016`

Comment: @GregorySuvalian's suggestions look good to me. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility may shed some more light on the container version compatibility issues.